# How to pass data between UITableViews in NavigationController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In my first tableViewController has `navigationViewController.push(myNextController, animated: true)` and I want to segue to another `TableViewController`. What I am trying to figure out for hours is that when I select a row in my first `tableViewController`, I want to move to the next `tableview`. Right now, when I select a row, my next `tableVIew` has the same data.  I want each cell to have differently saved cells

**Second table view controller**

The title is the navigation title and the myArray is an array:

```
 // globally declared
var dataArray = [String]()
var myArray = [String]()

 // this function is in my second table view controller, viewDidLoad()
func data(){
    myArray = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "Key")!
    dataArray = myArray
}

The dataArray is:

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if let getData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"key") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = getData[indexPath.row]
    }

     tableView.reloadData()
     return cell
   }
```

**first table view controller**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColorUtil.rgb(rgbValue: 0xFFFFF9)

    let getData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "category")!
    let nextViewController = TableView()
    nextViewController._titile = getData[indexPath.row]

    // so I access myArray from second table view controller because I want to 
    //get data of each selected cell. But this is a problem. 

    nextViewController.myArray = getData
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)

}

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

if let getData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"category") {
    cell.textLabel?.text = getData[indexPath.row]
}

 return cell
```

}

Why do they have the same cells? How am I able to accomplish this without using a storyboard? I want to programmatically write code. By the way, I am using UITabBar as well. Thanks!

Comment: *each cell has different sets of cells* what does this mean?

Comment: Ahh, sorry for my bad English!!! Just they have the same cells!! So I want each cell to have differently saved cells!

Comment: If the array containing the metadata for the cells changes. Then you must run `tableview.reloadData()` so your table would refresh its cells...

Comment: Nah, a newly created cell in the second table view controller affects all cells of my first table view controller. How it is not about reload()....

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean affect?

Comment: Okay, so in my ftvc(first table view controller), I can add cells by a button. Then For example, after my ftvc fills with three cells, I select one of them, which leads to stvc. And when I add some cells by a button there, my stvc will have some cells, but when I select another cell in my ftvc, they also have the same cells. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: A cell retrieves its data by an Array. Either you are using the **same** array for both tableViews **or** you are not updating your Array once you go back to tableView **or** somewhere in your code you need to run reloadData() and you aren't. Don't comment here, but update your question highlighting where you reloadData and manage the array changes

Comment: also include `cellForRowAt` func of Your **firstViewController** in your question and viewDidLoad

Comment: I can't find the issue. Can you share all your code on github and share the link